# What is the best practice to scale a select/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list (of an undetermined length, that can keep on growing) of values. For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1, some test</option>
  <option value="2">2, some text</option>
  <option value="3">3, some text</option>
  <option value="4">4, some text</option>
  <option ...... add 100 more options> ..
</select>
```

What would be the best practice/user friendly way to support such a long list? I imagine that a user might find it frustrating to scroll through a super long list. 
I am trying to minimize the user's scroll time, by presenting the most recent values at the top of the drop down, but if she/he would like to go to the first element in the drop down it would require a lot of scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<select>`, how about changing it to HTML5 `<datalist>`, which is like this:

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

By the way, you can type the first letter using the `<select>`, so my suggestion will be sort your data according to the first letter. Because it will help the user to go to the sub-option directly.

Comment: [According to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/datalist), using `datalist` is pretty risky if one needs cross-browser compatibility (64% compatibility). It is a pretty cool element though, I hope it'll come to more browsers fast.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add a searchfield to the dropdown? 
Something like this: **http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/**

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data would you like to display ? Maybe there is another way than **select** to display them ? In fact, for dozens of items, **select** is not the best choice, unless you use by example a JQuery plugin like **jsearchdropdown** and in this case the user must know what he's looking for.

Comment: a bunch of integers for the value, some random text for the context